# Update table records - Add '00' for each 2 Numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with many millions of records, in oracle. And in this table there's a field that needs to be updated.
I need to add a '00' for each to numbers. Like this:

```
1234 -> 120034

123456 -> 1200340056
```

The length of this field can vary between 2 and 16 numbers. 
Because of this variation in length, I have no ideia how to make this update.
Can same one give a hand please?

Thank you.

Comment: '00' position is fixed after two index? what to do if length exceeding 16? and what query you have tried so far

Comment: @Prathyush, The length of the field will be increased to fit all cases. I'm sorry I haven't tried any query so far, I honestly have no idea how to do this update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_value = REGEXP_REPLACE(
                   REGEXP_REPLACE(
                     your_value,
                     '(\d\d)',
                     '\100'
                   ),
                  '^((\d\d00)*\d\d)00$',
                  '\1'
                );
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you. Next time i have to look into REGEXP first.